# Add Local Group User policies with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, citrix, gpo

I have a rather simple task. Is there any way to add a Group Policy under User-Configuration (particularly logon / logoff PowerShell scripts) ? I have seen tons of guides [Like this one](http://woshub.com/running-powershell-startup-scripts-using-gpo/), but they are making it via GUI. I'd like to run a script, so all files are mapped from Network Fileshares.

I need an automation to configure master-image for citrix environment. (Maybe this can be achieved with BIS-F? or is there some sort of registry key? )

Thank you in Advance!

Here's a screenshot of this Policy (i can't make my own, because it's in German)

[image: gpedit]

Answer (score 0):

The New-GPO cmdlet creates a GPO with a specified name. By default, the newly created GPO is not linked to a site, domain, or organizational unit (OU).

See more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/new-gpo?view=win10-ps

Comment: thus, it is may be a way to create new group policy, but you can't add scripts,